# How to make SSRS filter selection optional?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services to create a new report.

This report has 2 optional parameters that can be selected by users or users can leave them blank. Both are dropdown selection.

The problem that I'm facing is, I had set both parameters to Allow Null Value, but not Allow Blank Value. When I click on View Report button without select any filter criteria, the report give me 0 records. But if I selected a value for both dropdown selection, the reports give me result.

`@Package` is `varchar(100)` and `@Plant` is `tinyiny`.

I write the `WHERE` clause in this way.
please help and much appreciate.

```
WHERE (@Package ='' OR PACKAGE_TYPE LIKE '%' + @Package + '%') AND
 (@Plant IS NULL OR PLANT_ID = @Plant )
```

Comment: And your question is ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when no filter criteria are selected, both `@Package` and `@Plant` are `NULL`?

In your `WHERE` clause above, you're only handling `@Plant` `NULL` values.

You need to check for `NULL` `@Package`, too, something like:

```
WHERE (@Package IS NULL OR @Package ='' OR PACKAGE_TYPE LIKE '%' + @Package + '%') AND
  (@Plant IS NULL OR PLANT_ID = @Plant )
```